# Normal ordering of operators multiplied by scalars

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, syntax, physics

I have the following code for normal ordering of two Boson operators $a(x),\,b(y)$:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
ClearAll[NonCommutativeMultiply]

NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1


NonCommutativeMultiply[a_] := a
SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, {OneIdentity, Flat}]

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];


NO[x___] := NonCommutativeMultiply[x];

NO[] := 1
NO[x_] := x

NO[left___ ** a[x_] ** SuperDagger[a][y_] ** right___] := 
NO[left ** SuperDagger[a][y] ** a[x] ** right] + left ** right*KroneckerDelta[x - y]

NO[left___ ** b[x_] ** SuperDagger[b][y_] ** right___] := 
NO[left ** SuperDagger[b][y] ** b[x] ** right] + left ** right*KroneckerDelta[x - y]


NO[left___ ** a[x_] ** SuperDagger[b][y_] ** right___] := NO[left ** SuperDagger[b][y] ** a[x] ** right]  
NO[left___ ** b[x_] ** SuperDagger[a][y_] ** right___] := NO[left ** SuperDagger[a][y] ** b[x] ** right]
NO[left___ ** a[x_] ** b[y_] ** right___] := NO[left ** b[y] ** a[x] ** right]
NO[left___ ** SuperDagger[a][x_] ** SuperDagger[b][y_] ** right___] :=
NO[left ** SuperDagger[b][y] ** SuperDagger[a][x] ** right]


NO[Times[u_, y___]] := u NO[y]
```

which works fine, e.g:

```
NO[b[q] ** a[k] ** SuperDagger[a][q]]
(*=> b[q] KroneckerDelta[k - q] + SuperDagger[a][q] ** b[q] ** a[k])
```

The problem is if the operators product is multiplied by scalars.
`NO[Times[u_, y___]] := u NO[y]`  takes care of the problem if you have one scalar e.g:

```
NO[u b[q] ** a[k] ** SuperDagger[a][q]]
(*=> u (b[q] KroneckerDelta[k - q] + SuperDagger[a][q] ** b[q] ** a[k]) )
```

However I am stuck on how to make it work in case you have many different scalars mutliplying the operators, e.g:

```
NO[u v w b[q] ** a[k] ** SuperDagger[a][q]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NO[Times[x__, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z___]] := x z NO[y]
NO[Times[x___, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z__]] := x z NO[y]
```

should do the trick in all situations:

[image]

Depending of the canonical ordering of `Times` it might not be necessary to include both versions but better save then sorry.

Comment: thanks! Seems to do the trick, `NO[Times[x___, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z__]] := x z NO[y]` wouldn't be sufficient? `x___` covers `x__`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but in the case `x___` one needs an expression matching a non empty sequence for `z__` which might not be given. Depending on the kind of products and expression ordering of `Times`  `NO[Times[x__, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z___]] := x z NO[y]` might not cover cases where like `a ** b*Z[c]*...` just to be save I would keep both. Allowing empty sequences for both `x` and `z` might be the cleanest solution `NO[Times[x___, y_NonCommutativeMultiply, z___]] := x z NO[y]` after all but when I wrote the answer I was not sure wether this would work. I think it does now.